# fragment page to map Activity and then get the location and sent it back to the fragment page

Tags: android, google-maps

Fragment page has an EditText and I set the OnClickListener. When I click on the EditText, it will go to a map activity. The latitude is got in the map activity and send it back to the fragment. When I back to the fragment, the latitude should be displayed on the EditText. However, there are nothings on the EditText. How can I solve this problem?

```
final EditText latitude=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    latitude.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String lat=sharedPreferences.getString("latitude","");
            String lon=sharedPreferences.getString("longitude","");

            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            latitude.setText(lat);

        }
    });
```

This is the code in the fragment page.
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

```
    LatLng hk=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    final Marker Place=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hk).title("HK").draggable(true));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hk));

    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            LatLng location=Place.getPosition();
            Double lat=location.latitude;
            String lat2=lat.toString();
            Double lon=location.longitude;
            String lon2=lon.toString();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("latitude",lat2).putString("longitude",lon2).commit();

            Place.setTitle("latitude"+lat2+"\n"+"longitude"+lon2);

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        }
    });











    }
```

This the the code in map activity.

Answer (score 0):

There can be various ways to achieve this like with `startActivityForResult()`

```
final EditText latitude=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    latitude.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),MapsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,001);
        }
    });
```

In the this activity put this method which will pass activity result to your fragment.

```
  Fragment your_fragment;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fragmenet.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

In your fragment class put this code

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        latitude.setText(data.getDoubleExtra("lat",0)+ "," +data.getDoubleExtra("lng",0));
    }
```

In next activity

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            LatLng location=Place.getPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("lat", location.latitude);
            intent.putExtra("lat", location.longitude);
            setResult(001, intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
```